# Can write on /opt/something locally but cannot when deployed with k8 on the cloud

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a problem that might seem trivial to you, I'm trying to deploy an OpenSource application on kubernetes, it worked perfectly with my local cluster on Minikube.

Now I have the charge of deploying to the cloud with a basis that is prebuilt and doesn't work.

The problems I encounter on all my containers are always permissions issues, for example the application can't find/write on /opt/something (because ownership is set as root) but I just want it to copy files and read from them. On my local installation, everything is owned by root (uid and gid) but it works fine for executing file inside this file path.

I've tried mounting a PVC to no chance
I've tried allowing privesc
I've tried setting fsGroup, runAsGroup and runAsUser to the value of my user (1000)

I'm quite lost and this is the first time I do something with k8 so a big bit loss

I sense the solution is really simple but can't figure it out

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The mount point of a volume is owned by the `root` user. Another user cannot make changes to the directory , you can only read/write the files that get mounted.

There are few workarounds for this

- **Init container** : write an init container in your deployment/pod/replicaset manifest that `chown` the directory to the user that the image use.
- **Mount on another point** : if the image has to edit the /opt/something files and make changes to the directory , mount your persistent volume somewhere else and copy them there by defining 'command' in your k8s manifest.
- **Another image** : use an image that uses root user.

I had encountered the same situation which i had to extract a file inside a volume with another user and i would get permission denied.
and these were the solutions i found.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to `chown` the directory to that user either through initContainer or write your own Dockerfile on top of that

But one other solution can be that you run your pod with root user, even though it is not recommended security wise, but you can still run your container as root so that you are able to run the application...

You can set below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  containers:
  - name: demo
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    securityContext:
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```

Again this is not the best solution as you are running the container as root which can cause issues.